# Why does this code snippet give a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am not able to understand why this simple code gives a segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector <vector <int>> graph;
    graph [0] = vector <int> ();
    graph [0].push_back(0);
    cout << graph[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the problem?

Comment: What does `graph[0]` contain when you use it?

Comment: After declaring all the lines give error, if I comment them out one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared an empty vector

```
vector <vector <int>> graph;
```

So you may not use the subscript operator to change non-existent elements of the vector.

You could declare the vector at least with one element like

```
vector <vector <int>> graph( 1 );
```

In this case this statement

```
graph [0] = vector <int> ();
```

shall be removed and you may write

```
graph [0].push_back(0);
cout << graph[0][0];
```

And alternative approach is to use one more the method `push_back` for the initial object.

```
vector <vector <int>> graph;
graph.push_back( {} );
graph [0].push_back(0);
cout << graph[0][0];
```

Comment: This is very informative. Thank you.

I am trying to input a graph's edge data to form an adjacency list. I think I'll have to specify the number of nodes and initialize the graph to have that many empty vectors initially. I was hoping to do it dynamically though. 

Still thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
vector <vector <int>> graph;
graph [0] = vector <int> ();
```

Because you're accessing element 0 of an empty vector. First, give it some elements:

```
graph.emplace_back();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use `push_back` or resize `graph` from the start:

```
vector<vector<int>> graph;
graph.resize(1);
graph[0].push_back(0);
cout << graph[0][0];
```